# Application of Pythagorean Theorem in vectors in n-dimension space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm attempting (and failing) at studying Real Analysis. I'm particularly stuck on this basic question about vectors, so if anyone could give me some hints with the algebra that be immensely appreciated. I'm also particularly bad with technology so I'll be posting a photo of my work typed into Microsoft Word.

[Image of question and work performed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lH0q.png)

I have no idea how to progress past here. What are the algebraic steps for squaring a series? Is my attempt even remotely on the right path? Also note that the **e** vector represents the standard basis and not Euler's Number.

Comment: There are no series in this problem only finite sums.

Comment: @Digitallis A finite sum is a series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $e_i$ of the standard basis are [orthonormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormality). Since $\Vert x\Vert^2=\sum_{i=1}^jx_i^2$ while $\Vert y\Vert^2=x_{j+1}^2$, the result is $\sum_{i=1}^jx_i^2+x_{j+1}^2=\sum_{i=1}^{j+1}x_i^2$.

Comment: Why does the standard basis e_i vanish when you calculate the squared norms of x and y?

Comment: @Dylan I think you're asking why $\Vert\sum_{i=1}^jx_ie_i\Vert^2=\sum_{i=1}^jx_i^2$. You need to prove this statement of the Pythagorean theorem, by induction on $j$. It helps to use $\Vert u\Vert=u\cdot u$, [together with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) $e_j\cdot e_k=\delta_{jk}$.

Comment: Is induction really necessary? I just had a thought, the standard basis vector has a length of 1 unit. So when calculating the norm of the standard basis, could we not just say it "vanishes" as we multiply its length 1 onto the unknown vector x?

Comment: @Dylan OK, I take back the need for induction, but your argument is vague. Instead write$$\left\Vert\sum_{i=1}^jx_ie_i\right\Vert^2=\sum_{i=1}^jx_ie_i\cdot\sum_{k=1}^jx_ke_k=\sum_{ik}x_ix_ke_i\cdot e_k=\sum_{ik}x_ix_k\delta_{ik}=\sum_{i=1}^jx_i^2.$$

Comment: This helps so much! Thank you!!